# right way to construct and accept GET request in Laravel with long parameter (array)

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel. I do not know the right way to construct and accept GET requests.

I need to send the following request (`en` and `es` are language codes):

```
translation/next-word/en/es
```

and in Controller I have

`public function getNextWord($langfrom, $langto) {`

However, now new requirement came and I also have to send a list of IDs (on my client side it is an array (for instance, `[1,5,12,15]`), but it could be long list (about 100 IDs). Thus I am not sure how to send this ID array to controller and also accept it in controller method.

My old client side request (without categories):
    // var categories = [1,2,5,6,17,20];

```
var url = "translation/next-word/en/es";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET"                
        }).success(function(data){
            ...
        });
```

Comment: Where's the data? sent by ajax to the server?

Answer (score 0):

For get, change your controller like this,

```
public function getNextWord() {
    $langfrom = $_GET['langfrom'];
    $langto = $_GET['langto'];
}
```

In ajax send the data like this,

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET"  ,
        data: {langfrom:langfrom,langto:langto}   <----- passing from GET     
    }).success(function(data){
        ...
    });
```

If you wan to get in parameters like this,

```
public function getNextWord($langfrom, $langto) {
```

Then ajax should look like this,

```
$.ajax({
        url: url +"/" + langfrom + "/" langto,  <----- passing as parameter
        method: "GET"  ,            
    }).success(function(data){
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, you handle GET requests by making a route in your `routes.php` file and then a corresponding method in a controller class to actually handle the request. In your case, because you want to also pass in an unknown number of IDs, I would suggest making that into a query parameter. You can format that however you want, although I would suggest using something like commas to divide the data in your URL. So in the end, your URL would look something like this:

```
example.com/translation/next-word/en/es?categories=1,2,5,6,17,20
```

routes

```
Route::get('translation/{nextWord}/{from}/{to}', 'TranslationController@translate');
```

TranslationController

```
public method translate($nextWord, $from, $to, Request $request)
{
    //get the categories passed in as a query parameter
    $input = $request->all();
    $categories = $input['categories'];
    $categories = explode(',',$categories); //turn string into array

    //actually translate the words here (or whatever you need to do)
    $translated = magicTranslateFunction($nextWord, $from, $to);

    //also you can now use the categories however you need to

    //once you're done doing everything return data
    return $translated;
}
```

Inside your javascript, you'll just want to turn your array of categories into a comma delimited string and pass that to make the URL I started the post with.

```
var categories = [1,2,5,6,17,20];
var categoriesString = categories.join();
var url = "translation/next-word/en/es?categories="+categoriesString;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",               
        success: function(data) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

### Edit - using $.ajax 'data' setting

Instead of appending the categories as a string to the URL, you can just pass in the array directly as part of the 'data' setting of your ajax call.

```
var categories = [1,2,5,6,17,20];
var url = "translation/next-word/en/es";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        data: {
           "categories": categories
        },
        success: function(data) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Laravel will actually convert this correctly to a PHP array, so you don't need to do any special parsing in your controller. Just take it in like normal and use it:

TranslationController

```
public method translate($nextWord, $from, $to, Request $request)
{
    //get the categories passed in as a query parameter
    $input = $request->all();
    $categories = $input['categories']; //already a PHP array

    //actually translate the words here (or whatever you need to do)
    $translated = magicTranslateFunction($nextWord, $from, $to);

    //also you can now use the categories however you need to

    //once you're done doing everything return data
    return $translated;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way not to send categories via url?

Comment: Well, you can add them to the 'data' key of your ajax call instead. This still appends them to the URL but it doesn't look like it from the javascript side. The only downside is that this will format it in a weirder way so you have to parse it correctly on the PHP side of things. I will update my answer to show you that.

Comment: Okay that is updated. I misspoke about the PHP parsing - Laravel will take care of that for you.

Comment: Did this address what you needed, or did you want to pass that data a different way?